# Linker error ( VS 2005 vs VS 2012 )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

I am trying to build `libxml2` library with VS 2012 compiling and linking against `DDK 7` headers and libraries. With VS 2005 it builds fine but with VS 2012, I am getting a linker error. On close inspection of symbols generated -

On VS 2005,

```
Found __imp___vsnprintf
    Referenced in error.obj
    Referenced in xmlreader.obj
    Referenced in xmlwriter.obj
    Referenced in xmlstring.obj
    Loaded msvcrt.lib(msvcrt.dll)
```

On VS 2012,

```
error.obj     : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf  
                               referencedin function ___xmlRaiseError
xmlreader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf
xmlwriter.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf
xmlstring.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf
```

`__imp__vsnprintf`, `__imp___vsnprintf` on VS 2012 and VS 2005 respectively for the same function ( Notice the extra `_` mark before `vsnprintf` in VS 2005). I looked at the compiler and linker options for the VS 2005 and VS 2012 in the build log. Both are the same. With the `showIncludes` option passed to the compiler, I see the exactly same set of headers used for the source files on both VS 2005 and VS 2012.

Why is yet the symbol generation in VS 2012 being different ? How to resolve the issue with out compiling and linking against default headers and libs  ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that all libraries are built with the same RuntimeLibrary (DLL, MT/ST, Debug/Release) parameter?
Also, what version of MSVCRT.lib you are linking with?

Comment: @MichaelSh Compiling using `/MD`, `/D NDEBUG`. And `msvcrt.lib` is available in the `DDK 7/lib/wxp`.

Comment: Try using msvcrt.lib from the folder where VS2012 is installed

Comment: @MichaelSh It's not an option in my case because linking against default `msvcrt.lib` with compiler option `/MD` requires shipping of `msvcrt110.dll` with my application. However, I opened the msvcrt.lib with the notepad, and the symbol what VS 2012 compiler is looking for is present.

Comment: Can you post complete command line for the linker? Do you have NODEFAULTLIB set to ignore msvcrt.lib and have the non-default msvcrt.lib explicitly listed as a dependency?

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use** `DDK` for building user-mode components. `DDK` stands for `Driver Development Kit`. Using it for user mode is undefined behavior. Use `SDK` instead.